# why does the mse loss had a sudden jump?

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, mse

i'm working on a regression problem using neural network. the mse loss would decrease at the beginning of train and the accuracy is satisfactory, yet, when the train process goes on, the loss had a huge jump, and maintain at a certain value,[image: mse loss and accuracy]like the curve in the picture. i don't know why and how to fix it? and i wanna ask if i could use the train coefficient before the jump, like train step at 8000, as my final result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case of model training where the value of the accuracy metric stops improving (and even get worse) from a certain number of training epochs.
I'll suggest you to implement **Early Stopping** meaning that, "yes", you can take the training accuracy at step 8000 as you final result if your only goal is to minimize the training loss.

[This TF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping) explains **how** to implement Early Stopping with Tensorflow's `tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping()` function.

However if your goal is a model that generalizes well on unseen data (test/validation data) as this is generally the case, you might want to evaluate your model's test accuracy in order to take it into account when implementing Early Stopping.

[This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-practical-introduction-to-early-stopping-in-machine-learning-550ac88bc8fd) gives a very good example of end-to-end implementation of early stopping with Tensorflow.